Eviction of a non-tenant
Consider this situation - Alice and Bob live together in a house owned by Alice’s friend. Alice has been paying rent but has no written lease or rental agreement with her friend.
Alice leaves with Bob still in residence with the understanding between them that Bob will vacate in 30 days. If Bob refuses to leave at that time what recourse does the owner have and what would have improved their situation? Possibly a written notice at the start or a 30 day rental agreement for $1.
In  California

IANAL but I think Bob is technically trespassing. He hasn't been given permission to live there by the owner, and he's not a guest of the current resident (there is no resident since Alice moved out). The owner can treat them like any other squatter, and call the police if they don't move out voluntarily.

@Barmar While Alice is not in possession, it isn't clear that her lease has terminated. She asked Bob to move out, but it isn't clear what she told her landlord. Someone can be a guest while a tenant is not in possession. Indeed, that is the usual thing in the cases of house sitting and pet sitting.

@ohwilleke I assumed "Alice leaves" meant that she moved out permanently (and notified the landlord of this), not temporarily like a vacation. Since she was paid up through the end of the month, she can have guests during that time even while she's gone, but not after.

@Barmar That is possible, but the question isn't clear on that point.

The landlord can end the tenancy agreement with Alice
new-south-wales
The landlord and Alice have a valid tenancy agreement under the Residential Tenancies Act 2010, even though the landlord has committed an offence by not having it in writing. The agreement will be for an initial period of 6 months, after which it will revert to a month-to-month tenancy. The landlord may end the tenancy at the end of any of these periods provided they give at least 30-days notice to Alice.
Alice is entitled to have guests stay over and is not required to be present on the property, so, as described, Alice is in compliance with her obligations as long as she keeps paying the rent (which can be $0) and observes all the other terms of the lease.
However, depending on the circumstances, the law may recognise Bob as a tenant of the landlord (s77).
Alice is entitled to sub-let or add a co-tenant with the landlord's approval, which may not be unreasonably refused for partial occupancy but may be refused on any grounds for whole transfers. It appears that she has not sought and not been granted this approval, and this would put her in breach of the lease if Bob is, in fact, a tenant. This would make her liable for any damages the landlord suffers because of Bob's tenancy.
